# Override "show" resource route in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
resources :some_resource
```

That is, there is a route `/some_resource/:id`

In fact, `:id` for `some_resource` will always be stored in session, so I want to override the path `/some_resource/:id` with `/some_resource/my`. Or I want to override it with `/some_resource/` and remove the path GET `/some_resource/` for index action.

How can I reach these two goals?

Comment: I'm not sure what your resource is, but it sounds like it may be a singular resource, in which case you could set it up as `resource :some_resource` instead? There's more about singular resources here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources if you're interested.

Comment: I saw it. It's not going to help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your routes.rb put:

```
get "some_resource" => "some_resource#show"
```

**before** the line

```
resources :some_resource
```

Then rails will pick up your "get" before it finds the resources... thus overriding the get /some_resource

In addition, you should specify:

```
resources :some_resource, :except => :index
```

although, as mentioned, rails won't pick it up, it is a good practice

Answer (score 13):

[Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236731/514866) works fine (and I used that approach for some time), but there is a standardized way. In the [Official Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) the use of **collection routes** is preferred.

Collection routes exist so that Rails won't assume you are specifying a resource `:id`. In my opinion this is better than overriding a route using precedence within the `routes.rb` file.

```
resources :some_resource, :except => :index do
  get 'some_resource', :on => :collection, :action => 'show'
end
```

If you need to specify more than collection route, then the use of the block is preferred.

```
resources :some_resource, :except => :index do
  collection do
    get 'some_resource', :action => 'show'
    # more actions...
  end
end
```