# Modify rails route to display usersname instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do this:

> site.com/username

instead of this:

> site.com/users/1

What's the best way to set up routes and users controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming this is a GET request. So it would be like:

Route definition

```
get '/:username', to: 'users#show', as: 'user_by_name'
```

Usages:

```
link_to 'Show', user_by_name_path(user.username)
```

`user` in `user.username` should be replaced with actual variable.

More in [Non Resourceful Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) in official guide.

If you want to override this from a `users` resource, you can follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/18261912/383912. You need to use 'member' instead of 'collection' for `show` route.

Comment: +1, should `get '/:username'` instead get `'/users/:username'` OP want url like this `site.com/username`

Comment: oh yes, thanks for pointing. i assume he is aware of the side effects of these.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the path to be at the route:

```
resources :users, path: '', only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
```

You can leave out the `:only` if you want the index page and create action for users to map to `/`.

Check out [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for easily using the username as the id in the route.

Make sure you define other routes for example `/about` before the users route, or they will be interpreted as user ids.

Answer (score 1):

Something you might want to look at: **[How to create app-wide slug routing for Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375222/how-to-create-app-wide-slug-routing-for-rails-app)**

If you're going to be routing to `domain.com/:username` & have other content types, you will need a way to process them all without conflict.