# Is it possible to disable the standard PUT route in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 has introduced `PATCH` requests to be the default request method when doing the (common) partial updates on objects. This is conformal to HTTP standards and a good (older) post discussing this decision can be found here:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/

When you define a resource in `config/routes.rb` like

```
    resources :books
```

then the following routes are created per default in rails 4:

```
    GET     /books       books#index
    GET     /books/:id   books#show
    POST    /books       books#create
    DELETE  /books/:id   books#destroy
    PATCH   /books/:id   books#update
    PUT     /books/:id   books#update
```

As I am developing a new application and do not have to care about backwards compatibility, I would like to remove the obsolete `PUT` route.

Is there an easy way for accomplishing this in `config/routes.rb`?

---

**Explanation why this `PUT` route bothers me:** I am using the [swagger-docs gem](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs) for automatically generating a swagger documentation for my API. Due to the described behavior, I always have two endpoint definitions for update requests (`PUT` and `PATCH`) for every resource. Plus as this is a potentially deprecating route, I would like my API to not support it from today on.

---

**UPDATE** due to the first answers heading in the wrong direction I would like to clarify: I do not want to remove the 'update' action, but only the obsolete PUT route while keeping the PATCH route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer my own question: no, it is currently not possible to disable the default generation of the PUT/PATCH combination in rails 4, which can be clearly seen when looking at the source of ActionDispatch::Routing at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb and especially those lines:

```
      def set_member_mappings_for_resource
        member do
          get :edit if parent_resource.actions.include?(:edit)
          get :show if parent_resource.actions.include?(:show)
          if parent_resource.actions.include?(:update)
            patch :update
            put :update
          end
          delete :destroy if parent_resource.actions.include?(:destroy)
        end
      end
```

Obviously, there is (currently) no conditional for excluding the `PUT` route. I will prepare an issue or pull request for this and come back later with the result of that.

Until then, the best workaround would be what Jorge de los Santos has suggested, although this would pretty much pollute `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is, check the docs:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

```
resources :photos, except: :update
```

PATCH and PUT are meant for different uses. As long as the update is partial you should be using PATCH but if you are updating everything you must use PUT.
This can sound confusing, but for example let's suppose you are updating the associated model, this might be considered a put action instead of a patch as long as you are not modifying a partial info, you are update the whole relation.

Also PUT is used to update or create, soy might be found it useful when adding nested resources.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/

---------------EDIT with solution:

To override puts ad:

```
PATCH 'route', to: 'books#update'
resources :books, except: :update
```

Rails will catch the patch before the resources and will disable the put and patch for update.

Reference:

[Override "show" resource route in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235718/override-show-resource-route-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using except: :update will remove both PUT and PATCH routes, which is not what I want. Regarding your explanation of the differences: that is correct, but the blog post I have linked in the question explains in a decent way, that we basically never perform real PUT requests in our APIs. You rarely replace whole objects (i.e. created_at) and also update-or-create makes no sense in many APIs because the ID is usually created by the database, not the API consumer, thus you must create via POST

Comment: I understand that but you have to be aware that:
1)Not all servers accepts patch as explained in my blog post
2)In an API the request update action doesn't know if the updated entity exists, either you have some kind of: entity not found error. Or you will find yourself updating something inexistent.
3)All PUT actions will redirect to a non existent route.

Editing with a kind of solution.

Comment: I see the point with not all server accepting PATCH but it plays not role for my application. I do not understand your second point, though. of course an update action will check whether the referenced element exists and throw an error otherwise. What's the difference between the expected behavior of PUT and PATCH here? Your third point is a good one, because: I want my API **not** to define the PUT route, so that consumers do not implement it. That is what I am here for. Also, the link above explains that they only kept the PUT route for backwards compatibility.

Comment: From a semantically point of view all arguments about the difference between PUT and PATCH would require rails to route these requests to different controller methods

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution suggestion. I will not mark the question as answer yet, because I am hoping for a more elegant (general) solution. If such does not exist, I will open an issue for ActionDispatch::Routing and suggest adding an option for deprecating the PUT route. Thanks for your effort, anyway!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of years and a major version of Rails later, there doesn't seem to be any progress on this issue.

This did the job for me at the top of `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  def put(*) end
  ...
```

Because the `set_member_mappings_for_resource` method mentioned in the OP's answer calls `put`, this simply makes it a no-op.

If you do need `put` routes, you could put them above this line. If you wanted to be fancy, you could define a `without_verbs(*verbs, &block)` method that temporarily replaces the various verb methods, yields, and then puts them back.

Answer (score 0):

another solution to override PATCH is the following:

```
resources :some_resources do
  member { patch action: :event }
end
```

This will result in calling the method `event` on the `SomeResourceController` when we call this route `PATCH /some_resources/:id`

or to disable it:

```
resources :some_resource, except: :update do
  member { put action: :update }
end
```