# Disable routing of PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

My application does not handle PATCH operations in the update method.  Is it possible to disable the routing of the PATCH HTTP verb for the update action on my resource declarations?

resources :groups, :user_connections, :users, except: [:patch]

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24091631/1202324
There are also some workarounds that may suite you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well no one else is going to answer my question so I'll post my current understanding.  According to [is-it-possible-to-disable-the-standard-put-route-in-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081946/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-standard-put-route-in-rails-4?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [update-action-of-a-restful-route-in-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347250/update-action-of-a-restful-route-in-rails-patch-or-put?rq=1) as of the time of this answer it is not possible to have PUT without PATCH or PATCH without PUT.  It is also not possible to have them serviced by different methods.  This appears to be the answer for both Rails 4.x and 5.x.