# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Hotel without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I`ve got these errors while testing ratings_controller.

```
1) RatingsController create action creates a rating if validations pass
     Failure/Error: post :create, rating: {value: 4, user_id: user, hotel_id: hotel}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Hotel without an ID
     # ./app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:6:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/ratings_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/ratings_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) RatingsController create action does not create rating if validations fail
     Failure/Error: post :create, rating: {value: 3}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Hotel without an ID
     # ./app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:6:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/ratings_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) RatingsController update action updates rating if validations ok
     Failure/Error: patch :update, value: 3, user_id: user.id, hotel_id: hotel.id
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"ratings", :hotel_id=>"1", :user_id=>"2", :value=>"3"}
     # ./spec/controllers/ratings_controller_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I dont know where they come from. Help me please if you can.
My  ratings_controller:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :signed_in_user
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
    @rating.hotel_id = @hotel.id
    @rating.user_id = current_user.id
    if @rating.save
        redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel), :notice => "Your rating has been saved"
    end
  end

  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    #@rating = current_user.ratings.find(@hotel.id)
    @rating = Rating.find_by_hotel_id(@hotel.id)
    if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
        redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel), :notice => "Your rating has been updated"
    end
  end

end
```

My ratings_controller_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe RatingsController do
  let(:rating) { FactoryGirl.create(:rating) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:hotel) { FactoryGirl.create(:hotel) }

  describe "create action" do
    before { sign_in rating.user }
    it "creates a rating if validations pass" do
      expect {
          post :create, rating: {value: 4, user_id: user, hotel_id: hotel} 
        }.to change(Rating, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "does not create rating if validations fail" do
      post :create, rating: {value: 3} 
      expect(response).to redirect_to(hotel_path(hotel))
    end
  end

  describe "update action" do
    before { sign_in hotel.user }
    it "updates rating if validations ok" do
      patch :update, value: 3, user_id: user.id, hotel_id: hotel.id
      rating.reload
      expect(rating.value).to eq(3);
    end

    it "updates rating if validations fail" do

    end
  end
end
```

Especially third error confusing me because `rake routes` shows me avaible route to ratings update action.

```
PATCH  /hotels/:id(.:format)       hotels#update
PUT    /hotels/:id(.:format)       hotels#update
```

Thanks!

`Rails - 4.0.8` 
`Ruby - 1.9.3p551`

**UPDATE 1:**
Sorry about routes. My mystake. Just copied the wrong lines.

```
rating PATCH  /ratings/:id(.:format)    ratings#update
        PUT    /ratings/:id(.:format)    ratings#update
```

Seems ok to me and works fine if I start server and test it manually.

Answer (score 1):

## About the id problem:

`@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])` expects the `params` hash to have a top-level `hotel_id` key. When you call the `create` method from the test, you nest the `hotel_id` inside the `ratings` key:

`post :create, rating: {value: 4, user_id: user, hotel_id: hotel}`

Thus `params[:hotel_id]` is nil. You need to add the `hotel_id` as a top-level key:

`post :create, rating: {value: 4, user_id: user, hotel_id: hotel}, hotel_id: hotel`

Alternatively, you can pass the nested `hotel_id` directly to the `find` method:

`@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:rating][:hotel_id])`

## About the route problem:

Your route is mapped to `HotelsController` (as seen in the `rake routes` output as `hotels#update`), but you are testing the `RatingsController`, so you get the

`No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"ratings", :hotel_id=>"1", :user_id=>"2", :value=>"3"}`.

Update your routes to route to the `RatingsController`'s `update` method instead of `HotelsController`, so you would have a `ratings#update` route.

**Update:**

In this case, the route is expecting an `id` parameter in the url: `/ratings/:id`, which you are not providing:

`patch :update, value: 3, user_id: user.id, hotel_id: hotel.id`

Either provide a specific rating id you want to update, or change your routes not to require the `id` parameter since you are finding the rating through the hotel anyway, so they will look like

`patch '/ratings', to 'ratings#update'`

instead of

`patch '/ratings/:id', to 'ratings#update'`.

If you defined your routes with `resources :ratings`, you can put the specific route above it, so it will be hit first by the router. A good idea would be to exclude it too: `resources :ratings, except: :update`. Or just use [collection routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235718/override-show-resource-route-in-rails) for some more info.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sorry about routes. I copied the wrong line. Check out the post please.